# Atmosphere without client side interaction

Tags: atmosphere

I have a situation where I have two users collaborating from two separate web browsers and a background process that needs to push information to both browsers independent of any communication.

So there are effectively three actors in this collaboration- two users and a background process.

I was wondering if Atmosphere supports this usecase. That is, can the background job cause information to be sent down to the browsers when it is ready to update the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the FAQ: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Server-Side-Broadcasts--OR-Communication-from-Server-Sides--OR--Non-Http-initiated-Broadcast

Short answer: yes, atmosphere support your use case.

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm am trying to do this on a jBoss. But I can't get the BroadcasterFactory Injected by annotation.